# CupertinoButton onPressed is error in Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

```js
class _LoginTipPage extends State<LoginTipPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('Login'),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            CupertinoButton.filled(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('Enabled'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here `onPressed: () {},` an error will be reported, but if `onPressed: null,` , then success.
I have upgraded to the latest version of Flutter and the latest version of Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do what the error message says: remove the `const` keyword from `CupertinoPageScaffold`. This is necessary because `(){}` is not constant.

If you want to keep the `const` keyword for slightly better performance, you can create a top-level or static function that does nothing

```
(static) void emptyFunction() {}
```

and then assign it to `CupertinoButton`:

```
onPressed: emptyFunction,
```